# Ad weight, giving advertisers a fair piece of the cake

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, ads

For the project I am currently involved in we have a select number of 'advertiser' groups that can add 'Offers' to our site that are displayed around other products and sometimes are related to the page the customer/buyer is viewing.

The current Ad system is completely random, and gives no preference except when trying to target a specific product. So, if `supplier1` has 9 adverts, and `supplier2` has 1 advert then `supplier1` gets much better value for their money as they get shown 9 out of 10 times.

How we are wanting to change this system is so that `supplier1` and `supplier2` should technically get the same exposure as each other regardless of the amount of ads they have in the system.

How would you suggest I try and approach this? I have looked at ad weight systems on StackOverflow; however, they don't seem to relate to groups.

Comment: why don't you just track, what ads did you shown, and based on that data, randomize other ads from different groups until all of them has the each ratio?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM advertisments a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM suppliers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) s ON a.suplplier_id = s.suplplier_id
ORDER BY RAND()
```

This query first selects one supplier by random (eg, every supplier have the same chance) (oh but if there are suppliers without any advertisement, you should filter them out), then it gets only advertisements of this user (that is how this INNER JOIN works) and orders them by random